# 500 TypeError: Not a string or buffer in express.js,node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, express

I m creating a Authentication page using **node.js,express.js** and **mysql2**. **Userid** and **password** from web page are coming in the **app.post('/login',...)** .But when i post the userid and password,the following error comes :

```
Express
500 TypeError: Not a string or buffer
at Hash.update (crypto.js:209:17)
at app.get.capture.responce (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji Site\app.js:455:52)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji         
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji 
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji   
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji 
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji  
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
at app.get.responseJSON (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji Site\app.js:33:3)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji 
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji  
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)Express 
500 TypeError: Not a string or buffer
at Hash.update (crypto.js:209:17)
at app.get.capture.responce (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji Site\app.js:455:52)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji   
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji    
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
at pass (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji   
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:145:5)
at nextRoute (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji        
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:100:7)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji 
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:167:11)
at app.get.responseJSON (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji Site\app.js:33:3)
at callbacks (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji  
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:164:37)
at param (c:\wamp\www\Guru Gobind Singh Ji    
Site\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:138:11)
```

And here is the code...

```
var application_root = __dirname,
    express = require("express"),
    mysql = require('mysql2'),
    path = require("path");

var app = express();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
 host : 'localhost',
 user : 'root',
 password : '123',
 database: "bbsbec"
 });

app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.cookieParser('shhhh, very secret'));
app.use(express.session());

 // Config

app.configure(function () {
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static(path.join(application_root, "public")));
app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
 });

app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "X-Requested-With");
  next();
 });

app.post('/login', function(request, response) {
 var username = request.body.name;
 var password = request.body.passwords;
 var hash = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(password).digest("hex");
 console.log(username);
 console.log(hash);
 var user;
 var pword;
 connection.query('SELECT * from pass', function(err, rows) {
  user = rows[0].userid;
  pword= rows[0].password;
  if(username == user  && password == pword)
   {
     request.session.regenerate(function(){
     request.session.user = username;   
     response.redirect('http://127.0.0.1/restricted');                  
     });
   }
else {
    response.redirect('http://127.0.0.1/AdminPanel/error.html');
     }
  });
   });

app.get('/logout', function(request, response){
request.session.destroy(function(){
     response.redirect('http://127.0.0.1/Admin-Panel/index.html');
   });
 });

app.get('/restricted', restrict, function(request, response){
  var capture = { responce: 'pass'};
  catchjson = JSON.stringify(capture);
  response.redirect('http://127.0.0.1/Admin-Panel/admin.html');
 });

 // Launch server
app.listen(5000, function(){
 console.log('Server running...');
});
```

Comment: What is the posted password? Is it definitely a string?

Comment: is req.body.passwordS right? I'm kinda intrigued by the plural

Comment: @lascort..yes i have used passwords word their intentially,just to avoid confusion...

Comment: In your form is it password or passwords?

Comment: @palanik..in the form it is passwords.

Comment: Maybe your're sending password `123` which actually is an integer? Try `var hash = require('crypto').createHash('md5').update(password.toString()).digest("hex");`.

Answer (score 0):

I am facing exactly the problem in my nodejs server.
I found that by removing the below part:

```
app.listen(5000, function(){
 console.log('Server running...');
});
```

The Server will work fine.